# Can we add different colors for different events using FSCalendar in swift?

Tags: swift, fscalendar

I have tried by adding different colors for different events using eventdefaultcolorfor() delegate but it did not worked for me. Actually is that possible to do i.e can we different colors for different dates of event

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to add different colors for different events. You can do something like this:-

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor?
    {
        let timeInterval = (date).timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
        let date = Helper().GetFullDateFromTimeStamp1(timeInterval)

        if  event1.contains(date) {
            return color1
        }
        else if event2.contains(date) {
            return color2
        }
        else
        {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

where event1 and event2 are arrays containing dates

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately eventColorsForDate is depreciated, as can be seen here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FSCalendar/2.7.9/Protocols/FSCalendarDelegateAppearance.html

```
- (nullable NSArray *)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar appearance:(FSCalendarAppearance *)appearance eventColorsForDate:(NSDate *)date FSCalendarDeprecated
```

If you use this method instead, it will produce the multiple colored dots (For every day -- edit your method to pick your dates)

```
- (NSArray<UIColor*> *)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar appearance:(FSCalendarAppearance *)appearance eventDefaultColorsForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    return @[[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#FB8F89"], [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#63C9EE"]];
}
```

[FSCalendar with multiple colored event dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRiZv.png)